# Display Woocommerce Sorting Dropdown as a List

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to replace the woocommerce sorting dropdown with a list and I have this so far which works ok.

The problem is the options are not converted to clickable working links. Any ideas how I can do it ?

```
<div class="wrapper-dropdown">
<span>I'm kinda the label!</span>
<ul class="dropdown">
<?php
    $catalog_orderby = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', array(
        'menu_order' => __( 'Default sorting', 'woocommerce' ),

    'popularity' => __( 'Sort by popularity', 'woocommerce' ),

    'rating'     => __( 'Sort by average rating', 'woocommerce' ),

    'date'       => __( 'Sort by newness', 'woocommerce' ),

    'price'      => __( 'Sort by price: low to high', 'woocommerce' ),

    'price-desc' => __( 'Sort by price: high to low', 'woocommerce' )
) );

if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_review_rating' ) == 'no' )
    unset( $catalog_orderby['rating'] );

foreach ( $catalog_orderby as $id => $name )
    echo '<li>' . esc_attr( $name ) . '</li>';
?>

</ul>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering where you added this? I have tried adding this via the `functions.php` file, however when I get to the `foreach` code, the website stops functioning.

Comment: Hi @Scott Hunter can we get these default product sorting options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `li` tag in the `foreach` loop should be something like this:

```
 echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) . '?orderby=' . $id . '" >' . esc_attr( $name ) . '</a></li>';
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

woocommerce_get_page_id() is depracted since WC 3.0

Use this code instead:

```
<ul class="woocommerce-ordering">
<?php
    $term = get_queried_object();
    $term_url   = get_term_link($term->term_id);
?>
<?php foreach ($catalog_orderby_options as $id => $name) : ?>
    <?php echo '<li><a href="' . $term_url . '?orderby=' . $id . '">' . esc_attr( $name ) . '</a></li>'; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```